# Is there a way to use the info from <tr> body fields in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tr

This is the code I want to place in a dropdown menu.

```
<tbody id="todoist_table_list_tbody">
  <tr>
      <td field='task_name'><a href="" field="task_link">Title </a></td>
      <td field='task_priority'>Priority</td>
      <td field='task_due_date'>Due Date</td>
      <td field='task_created_date'>Date Added</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right m-t-n-xs" 
          field='delete_task' type="submit"><strong>Delete</strong></button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right m-t-n-xs" 
          field='start_timer' type="submit"><strong>Start</strong></button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right m-t-n-xs" 
          field='stop_timer' type="submit"><strong>Stop</strong></button>
      </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have an existing body where all this works according to which row. I want to place all of this in a dropdown to select which ever node I want.

```
function end_timer(){
  if (timer_instance_dictionary != null){
    timer_instance_dictionary['end_time'] = moment().format()
    historical_times.push(timer_instance_dictionary)
    timer_instance.set({})
    clearInterval(timer_interval)
  }
}

$("button[field='start_timer']").click( function(){
  end_timer()
  task_id = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id")
  upload_dictionary = current_tasks_dictionary[String(task_id)]
  upload_dictionary['start_time'] = moment().format()
  upload_dictionary['task_id'] = task_id
  timer_instance.set(upload_dictionary)
})

$("button[field='stop_timer']").click( function(){
  end_timer()
})

$("button[field='delete_task']").click( function(){
  task_id = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id")
  upload_dictionary = current_tasks_dictionary[String(task_id)]
  upload_dictionary['deleted_time'] = moment().format()
  archived_tasks.push(upload_dictionary)
  todoist_delete_task(task_id)
  alert(task_id)
})
```

Comment: Quite confusing. What exactly do you want to do? Create dropdown menu which represents table rows? And what purpose of this dropdown?

Comment: He wants to create a drop down that handles the tasks currently being accomplished by the buttons (start, stop, delete)

Answer (score 3):

```js
function endTimer() {
    console.log("ended timer");
    // End timer code here
}
function startTimer() {
    console.log("started timer");
    // Start timer code here
}
function stopTimer() {
    console.log("stopped timer");
    // Stop timer code here
}
$(".choice").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val()==="Start") {
        startTimer();
    } else if ($(this).val()==="Stop") {
        stopTimer();
    } else if ($(this).val()==="End") {
        endTimer();
    }
});
$(".choice2").change(function() {
    var $val=$(this).val();
    if ($val==="Start") {
        startTimer();
    } else if ($val==="Stop") {
        stopTimer();
    } else if ($val==="End") {
        endTimer();
    }
    $(".choice2").each(function() {
        $(this).val($val);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='choice'><option>Timer Options</option><option>Start</option><option>Stop</option><option>End</option></select>
<select class='choice'><option>Timer Options</option><option>Start</option><option>Stop</option><option>End</option></select>
<select class='choice'><option>Timer Options</option><option>Start</option><option>Stop</option><option>End</option></select>
<select class='choice2'><option>Timer Options</option><option>Start</option><option>Stop</option><option>End</option></select>
<select class='choice2'><option>Timer Options</option><option>Start</option><option>Stop</option><option>End</option></select>
<select class='choice2'><option>Timer Options</option><option>Start</option><option>Stop</option><option>End</option></select>
```

Depending on what you want, I think the choice 1 class and choice 2 class display features that would be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate that, I want that functionality along with the fields that are procured by my jquery in the fields in a different dropdown as well, so that I can select the "task" and start the timer.